# For loop problem in JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using JQuery where i am trying to use the Cakephp Controller returned values in the JQuery input element..

I have two variables returned from my CakePHP controller action
$entries and $attributes..
$attributes will return the Fieldname and its type,size
$entries will return the Fieldname and the value submitted for the Field.

Both are array variables
Here i have created the Corresponding Input element using

```
             <?php foreach ($attributes as $r): ?>
               $("<div id= <?php echo $r['Attribute']['label'];?> ></div>").appendTo("#main");
               $("<input id=input<?php echo $r['Attribute']['id'];?> type= 'text' style= 'width:<?php echo $r['Attribute']['size'];?>px'value='<?php echo $attribute['Result']['value'];?>' ?> ></input><br>").appendTo("#main");
            $("<div id= <?php echo $r['Attribute']['type'];?> ></div>").appendTo("#main");
               <?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the above code where i am creating the Input element it shows me the correct Input element based on it.But within that input element when i tried to use like
value='' ?>

i have to keep the

```
               <?php endforeach;?>
```

where inside this only i can use the

How to do so.. Please suggest me..
SInce both are for loops i dont know how to use them since when i keep 


it will be creating as much number of times..

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".edi").click(function (){


               <?php foreach ($attributes as $r): ?>
               $("<div id= <?php echo $r['Attribute']['label'];?> ></div>").appendTo("#main");
               $("<input id=input<?php echo $r['Attribute']['id'];?> type= 'text' style= 'width:<?php echo $r['Attribute']['size'];?>px'value='<?php echo $attribute['Result']['value'];?>' ?> ></input><br>").appendTo("#main");
            $("<div id= <?php echo $r['Attribute']['type'];?> ></div>").appendTo("#main");
               <?php endforeach; ?> 
               $(".edi").hide();$(".vie").show();
               return false;
           });
      });
      </script>
```

EDIT:
I have kept
         for retriving the fields(type,size,fieldname) from the Attributes table..
         
is for retriving the That fields entries (label,value)...

On clicking the Edit button ,,, i am generating the input elements with sizes where i got it from $r['Attribute']['size'] as

$(" type= 'text' style= 'width:px'value='' ?> >
").appendTo("#main");
This shows me the correct generation of input elements with correct sizes of what it retrieves from the table..

Now inside this i.e. in the Input elements i want to show the value of this corresponding field of what i m retriving from using $r1['Result']['value'];
THis is where i am not able to make this values to show inside the Input Elements..Please help me......

Comment: please write the HTML/Javascript code result of foreach

Comment: Consider editing the latter portion of your post.The sentence is incomplete.I don't quite understand why you have php and js code mixed.And what should the final result be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding your question, but here is my answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edi").click(function() {
      <?php
        // loop over attributes
        foreach ($attributes['Attribute'] as $attribute):
          // loop over results
          foreach ($entries['Result'] as $result):
            // determine attribute value
            if ($result['fieldname'] == $attribute['fieldname']):
              $attribute['value'] = $result['value'];
            endif;
          endforeach;
          // build html string
          $html = String::insert(
            '<div id=":label"></div><input id="input:id" type="text" style="width: :size px" value=":value"></input><br><div id=":type"></div>',
            $attribute // see previous version for expanded version of this line
          );
          // append it using jquery
          echo "$('" . $html . "').appendTo('#main');";
        endforeach;
      ?>
      $(".edi").hide();
      $(".vie").show();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but here is a suggestion

Why not create a new view file to render the html you want to append to #main?
You can pass the attributes array from the controller action to the view file
For example, the view may be "ViewToAppend.ctp":

```
<?php foreach ($attributes as $r): ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $r['Attribute']['label'];?>" /></div>
    <input id="input<?php echo $r['Attribute']['id'];?>" type="text" style= "width:<?php echo $r['Attribute']['size'];?>px" value="<?php echo $attribute['Result']['value'];?>"> </input><br>
    <div id="<?php echo $r['Attribute']['type'];?>"></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

say your controller is "YourController", and the action you called is called "YourAction".
After the initial code where you fill up the $attributes array and set it as a view variable, check if the request is ajax.
If it is an ajax request, only render your smaller view "ViewToAppend.ctp"

```
class YourController extends AppController{
    var $components = array( ... , 'RequestHandler', ... );
    ...
    function YourAction( /* parameters */ ){

        /* initial code where you set up $attributes */

        $this->set('attributes',$attributes);

        if($this->params['isAjax'])
            render('/path/to/view/ViewToAppend','ajax');
    }
    ...
}
```

then you could call "YourAction" from javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edi").click(function (){

        $.ajax({
            url:'YourController/YourAction/...',
            success:function(msg){
                $('#main').append(msg);
                $(".edi").hide();
                $(".vie").show();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```